# Creating class with name dynamically via const_missing

Tags: ruby, binding, anonymous-class

I have this module:

```
module Api
  module ObjectMapper
    def self.const_missing const_name

      anon_class = Class.new do
        def self.foo
          puts self.class.name
        end
      end

      const_set const_name, anon_class
    end
  end
end
```

I want to be able to define an anonymous class at runtime with a method `foo` that can be called with `Api::ObjectMapper::User::foo`.  That function should print `User` to the screen.  Everything that I have tried has resulted in some sort of error or the function prints `Class` to the screen.

How do I fix my class and method definitions so that self.class.name resolves correctly?

Comment: It looks like you're after some very sweet meta programming, but I can't understand your end desire. Thank you for including your code attempt. Can you please start off by summarizing what you want to happen? Show some code that you'd like to run and the result you'd like it to produce.

Comment: I simplified the question.  Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: Dynamic Class Definition WITH A Class Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113479/ruby-dynamic-class-definition-with-a-class-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of a class is just the first constant that refers to it. The only problem with your original code is that you are using `self.class.name` instead of `self.name`:

```
module Api
  module ObjectMapper
    def self.const_missing const_name
      self.const_set const_name, Class.new{
        def self.foo
          name.split('::').last
        end
      }
    end
  end
end

p Api::ObjectMapper::User,      #=> Api::ObjectMapper::User
  Api::ObjectMapper::User.name, #=> "Api::ObjectMapper::User"
  Api::ObjectMapper::User.foo   #=> "User"
```

When you define a class method (singleton method on a class) the `self` is the class. The `self.class` is therefore always `Class`, whose name is `"Class"`.

---

*Original answer, which returns "User" instead of "Api::ObjectMapper::User"*

One way (no better than your closure-based solution) is to use an instance variable on the class:

```
module Api
  module ObjectMapper
    def self.const_missing const_name
      anon_class = Class.new do
        def self.foo
          puts @real_name
        end
      end
      anon_class.instance_variable_set(:@real_name,const_name)
      const_set const_name, anon_class
    end
  end
end

Api::ObjectMapper::User.foo
#=> User
```

A couple alternative, tighter syntaxes:

```
def self.const_missing const_name
  const_set const_name, Class.new{
    def self.foo; puts @real_name end
  }.tap{ |c| c.instance_eval{ @real_name = const_name } }
end

def self.const_missing const_name
  const_set const_name, Class.new{
    def self.foo; puts @real_name end
  }.instance_eval{ @real_name = const_name; self }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.  Since you are defining the anonymous class from within the scope of the const_missing method, you have const_name available to you which is the name of the class you're defining.  I'm not sure if that's the best solution, but it does work.  You have to redefine your class like this:

```
  anon_class = Class.new do
    define_singleton_method(:foo) do
      puts const_name
    end
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also define your foo method as class method

```
def self.const_missing const_name
  anon_class = Class.new do
    def self.foo
      puts self.class.name
    end
  end
end
```