# Class like Struct

Tags: ruby

I have task here: I must create a class which will be like class Struct. I have just started to learn Ruby and don't know how to create it. In my attempts, I was able to create a method that takes arguments and creates an array. Then I have to go through the array and all of the arguments, make the argument class, in which I can bring some value. But I don't know how to create methods that can create classes in Ruby.

I am asking for help if you have an example or know where to find it, I will be grateful!

my attempts:

```
class Hobbit

  def new(*params)
    "#{params.inspect}"
  end

end
```

Comment: How exactly do you want your clase to behave?

Comment: My task looks "Create the class  which will have the same behavior as 'Struct' class"

Comment: So basically, it's your homework?

Comment: Yes, but, in fact, I do not know how to create a method that will create the classes. I know how to create a class with parameters, etc.
But how to create a class that will create the classes, I do not understand (

Comment: What classes do you want to create ? You should explain in your question how you think you can solve your problem. It is not quite clear for the moment. My advice, the clearlier you can formulate a problem, the easier you can find ways to solve it.

Comment: OK, in short I need to implement on Ruby class Struct. And what i want it is an example of a method that can create classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assume all you want is

> And what i want it is an example of a method that can create classes

Check out [this question and the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113479/dynamic-class-definition-with-a-class-name) which shows you how to create a class dynamically given a class name. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.