# Getting the source of the method that defined dynamically

Tags: ruby

If the source of the any method is written explicitly in a file, [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393096/how-can-i-get-source-code-of-a-method-dynamically-and-also-which-file-is-this-me/22200271) a neat method to display the code:

```
A.instance_method(:foo).source
```

but if i define class and methods in it [dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113479/dynamic-class-definition-with-a-class-name) with

```
Object.const_set(dynamic_name, Class.new { def foo() puts 'bar' end })
```

i receive an error when try to get the source of this method, when use `instance_method(:foo).source` in this case

```
MethodSource::SourceNotFoundError: Could not load source for : No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - (eval)
```

How can i get the source of dynamically defined method? Is it possible at all?

Comment: According to the gem's documentation, there are [limitations](https://github.com/banister/method_source#limitations): it _"Cannot return source for C methods"_ and it _"Cannot return source for dynamically defined methods"_. So no, it's not possible with that gem.

Comment: @Stefan, i saw this, but there is no constraints to use only that gem

Comment: When using a library, write that.

Comment: done, my majesty

Answer (score 3):

At the very least, you can get bytecode (assuming you use MRI)

```
puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.disasm(A.instance_method(:foo))
# >> == disasm: #<ISeq:foo@->================================================
# >> 0000 trace            8                                               (   3)
# >> 0002 trace            1
# >> 0004 putself          
# >> 0005 putstring        "bar"
# >> 0007 opt_send_without_block <callinfo!mid:puts, argc:1, FCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
# >> 0010 trace            16
# >> 0012 leave
```

Comment: wow. %) i hopefully looking for a solution that can return `eval` friendly output...

Comment: @okliv: nah, I wouldn't count on that.

Comment: Hmm, my Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby, and Opal all raise a no method error.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: of course they do. :) But there is no cross-platform way, is there?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: IIRC, rubinius has better tools for this.